# ASP.NET 5 Ajax Валидация

Tags: ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Создал View:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post" role="form" class="ui large form">
        <div class="ui stacked segment">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                    <i class="users icon"></i>
                    <input asp-for="Surname" type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname"/>
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Surname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                    <i class="user icon"></i>
                    <input asp-for="Name" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name"/>
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="ui fluid large teal submit button"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Модель соответственную создал и в View объявил ее:

```
 public class UserViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter your surname!")]
    [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "{0} must have minimum {2} char.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter your name!")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "{0} must have minimum {2} char.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Контроль я сделал кажется неправильным. Чтобы проверить форму я отправляю Post запрос на тот же View а не на другой как показали примеры с интернета (например [Unobtrusive AJAX Form Validation in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460893/Unobtrusive-AJAX-Form-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC)):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Index(UserModel userModel, UserViewModel user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            userModel.CreateUser(Context, user);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Exam");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

Необходимо реализовать Ajax валидацию. Библиотеки jquery-validate и jquery-validation-unobtrusive подключены.

Если не трудно объяснить, есть ли разница между клиентской валидацией и серверной?

Comment: Клиентская валидация, собственно, срабатывает в браузере клиента. Но это не гарантия, т.к. можно запрос подделать и отправить данные какие угодно. Поэтому используют и клиентскую валидацию, которая как последняя инстанция проверяет всё ли ок в пришедших данных. Т.е. это не ИЛИ клиентская, или СЕРВЕРНАЯ валидация - нужны обе. Благо дело, все правила описываются лишь единожды )

Answer (score 1):

Если отвечать на не заданный вопрос "как реализовать ajax валидацию", то проверьте, что в web.config у вас включены следующие параметры:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
   <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
   </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

А также проверьте bundles.
Об этом нет упоминания в приведенной вами статье, так как там MVC 3.0.

Более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831451/ajax-beginform-doesnt-fire-ajax-script-falls-back-on-postback)